# Using mle2 function

Tags: r, debugging

I would like to find the MLE for parameters `epsilon` and `mu` in such a model:

$$X \sim \frac{1}{mu1}e^{-x/mu1}+\frac{1}{mu2}e^[-x/mu2}$$

```
library(Renext)
library(bbmle)
epsilon = 0.01

#the real model
X <- rmixexp2(n = 20, prob1 = epsilon, rate1 = 1/mu1, rate2 = 1/mu2)

LL <- function(mu1,mu2, eps){
  R = (1-eps)*dexp(X,rate=1/mu1,log=TRUE)+eps*dexp(X,rate=1/mu2,log=TRUE)
  -sum(R)
}
fit_norm <- mle2(LL, start = list(eps = 0,mu1=1, mu2 = 1), lower = c(-Inf, 0),
                 upper = c(Inf, Inf), method = 'L-BFGS-B')

summary(fit_norm)


But I get the error 

> fn = function (p) ':method 'L-BFGS-B' requires finite values of fn"
```

Comment: where is `rmixexp2` from? I think I could rewrite it myself, but it would be easier if you told us.

Comment: ... also, you haven't provided a starting value for `mu1`, which gives me an error (before we get to your error)

Comment: Or did you mean to fix the value of `mu1` ... ???

Comment: (I found a version of `rmixexp2` in the `Renext` package ... is this the version you were using?

Comment: @BenBolker  Yes, Im using Renext

Comment: @BenBolker  Yes, I lost it. I edited now, but still get the error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues here.  The primary one is that your likelihood expression is wrong (you can't log the components separately and then add them, you have to add the components and *then* take the log). Your bounds are also funny: the mixture probability should be [0,1] and the means should be [0, Inf].

The other problem you have is that with the current simulation design (n=20, prob=0.01), you have a high probability of getting *no* points in the first mixture component (the probability of a point being in the second component is 1-0.01=0.99, so the probability that *all* of the points are in the second component is 0.99^20 = 82%). In this case the MLE will be degenerate (i.e., you're trying to fit a two-component mixture to a data set that essentially only has one component); in this case any of these solutions will give equivalent likelihoods:

- prob=0, mu2=mean of the data, mu1=anything
- prob=1, mu1=mean of the data, mu2=anything
- mu1=mu2=mean of the data, prob=anything

With all these solutions, where you end up will depend very sensitively on starting conditions and optimization algorithm.

For this problem I would encourage you to use the **built-in** `dmixexp2` function from the `Renext` package (which correctly implements the log-likelihood as `log(p*Prob(X|exp1) + (1-p)*Prob(X|exp2))`) and the formula interface to `mle2`:

```r
fit_norm <- mle2(X ~ dmixexp2(rate1=1/mu1,rate2=1/mu2,prob1=eps),
                 data=list(X=X),
                 start = list(mu1=1, mu2 = 2, eps=0.4),
                 lower = c(mu1=0, mu2=0, eps=0),
                 upper = c(mu1=Inf, mu2=Inf, eps=1),
                 method = 'L-BFGS-B')
```

This gives me estimates of `mu1=1.58`, `mu2=2.702`, `eps=0`. `mean(X)` in my case equals the value of `mu2`, so this is the first case in the bulleted list above. You also get a warning:

> some parameters are on the boundary: variance-covariance calculations based on Hessian may be unreliable

There are also a variety of more specialized algorithms for fitting mixture models (especially those based on the expectation-maximization algorithm); you can look for packages on CRAN (`flexmix` is one of them).

This problem is small enough that you can visualize the whole log-likelihood surface by brute force (code below): the colours represent deviations from the minimum negative log-likelihood (the colour gradient is log-scaled, so there's a small offset to avoid log(0)). Dark blue represents parameters that are the best fit to the data, yellow are the worst.

[image]

---

```r
dd <- expand.grid(mu1=seq(0.1,4,length=51),
                  mu2=seq(0.1,4,length=51),
                  eps=seq(0,1,length=9),
                  nll=NA)
for (i in 1:nrow(dd)) {
    dd$nll[i] <- with(dd[i,],
                      -sum(dmixexp2(X,rate1=1/mu1,
                                    rate2=1/mu2,
                                    prob1=eps,
                                    log=TRUE)))
}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd,aes(mu1,mu2,fill=nll-min(nll)+1e-4)) +
    facet_wrap(~eps, labeller=label_both) +
    geom_raster() +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(trans="log10") +
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
    theme(panel.spacing=grid::unit(0.1,"lines"))
ggsave("fit_norm.png", type="cairo-png")
```

Comment: `Coefficients:    Estimate Std. Error z value     Pr(z)    
mu1   2.2845         NA      NA        NA    
mu2   5.2258     1.1685  4.4721 7.744e-06 ***
eps   0.0000         NA      NA        NA    `

Comment: if you switch eps and 1-eps, mu1 and mu2 are interchangeable.

Comment: What exactly this scale on plot describes? Thank you!

Comment: What is your question exactly? The x-axis on each panel is mu1, the y-axis is mu2, and the individual panels are showing a range of discrete eps values ...

Comment: I mean this color scale, I don't really understand its desription :/

Comment: More precisely what means dark blue for example, and what means green etc...

Comment: added description to the text above the plot.